# R command with sequential usages of <-

Tags: r

I once read the following R command

```
 lambda1.post[s]<-lambda1<-rgamma(1,a0+sum(Y[1:k]),b0+k)
```

In the above command, what does the term in the middle, i.e., `lambda1` used for? What is its difference with the following one

```
lambda1.post[s]<-rgamma(1,a0+sum(Y[1:k]),b0+k)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment operator (`<-`) is right associative and returns (invisibly) the value that it assigns.  Therefore:

`a <- b <- c <- d`

is the same as:

`a <- ( b <- ( c <- d ) )`

and is equivalent to:

```
c <- d
b <- c # or b <- d
a <- b # or a <- c or a <- d
```

This is just a shorthand for assigning the same value to multiple variables in one step.